# Enable/Disable editing of objects using C# MVC.net and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Ok i have a MVC.net front end using EF and SQL server for the database connectivity. I've created a large object with around 100 fields and a web ui to select and edit objects. I use EF to save changes back to the database. All good so far.

What i need to do now is implement some logic to stop edits for some objects and allow for others. For example:

object "01" 
is ok for everyone to make changes no changes needed the interface already covers this.

object "02" 
is "locked" against all changes when any user opens that object in the web app all fields should be disabled and the whole thing is read only.

object "03"
is locked for some users but unlocked for others so depending on the users roles they will either get the R/O all disabled view or the enabled edit anything view.

I could just right into this and start hacking something together but i just wondered if there is any "prefered" way or simpler way to achieve this? tnx.

Comment: You're asking about a way to implement Record Level Security, but you do not specify the parameters of your application. Do you have notion of Users/Roles? If so how do you maintain membership information? Is this large object a mapping of a similar entity in the database? On a tangent, Have you considered partitioning this collosal object?

Comment: The object is a legal case with many fields and many linked records partioning is probably not an option and its not about the size of the object the object could be just 2 fields its more about the process. I'm using .net Membership and roles to manage users again not really my main focus.  I could write code to check the users roles prior to saving i could also write code to determine if the record is locked and show a RO or Editable interface i just wondered if there was a common practice or design patern for this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the preferred way to do this is do it in your View. So you'd have something like

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Option1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Option1)
</p>

<p>
    Option2: @Option2
</p>

<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Option3)
    @if(@User.IsInRole("something")) {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Option3)
    }
    else {
        @Model.Option3
    }
</p>
```

Peronally I wouldn't have the @User.IsInRole(xxx) in the View I would have that precalculated in an IsAdmin boolean parameter that is passed through in the ViewModel but I put it there for conciseness in this example.